# starting a disconnected screen session at a specified size

Tags: gnu-screen

I would like to start a `screen` session (the program named `screen`) leaving it unattached in the background with it having either a specified size or inheriting the size from the terminal session.  It would be preferred to be able to specify the size so that it would not depend on doing it from an interactive terminal session.  I can already start a screen session manually at the terminal session size then manually detach it with `^Ad`.  I can already create a detached session (running an interactive shell like `bash -i`) at no specified size and it turns out to be 80x24 (almost never the size I want).  I have tried then having it do `stty cols 184 rows 50`, and while it set the numbers (as seen by doing `stty -a`) the wraparound remained at 80.

Any ideas how I can accomplish causing a background (detached) `screen` session to be started running an interactive shell (`bash`) at a specified size?