# How to launch a screen session and run an application with a specified terminal size

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I'm trying to use an old application that has a fixed screen size and really can't adapt to a different screen size. It looks like the screen command should be able to do this, but I can't figure out how. Note that the system console doesn't really resize due to dumb interactions between kernel mode switching, the VGA font and modern LCD sizes. 80 x 25 is a forbidden size on my hardware.

Some documentation said `-w [lines [cols]]` however when I tried `screen -w 80 25 ./runme` screen just complained that `-w` wasn't a command. I think the document was badly written and it was really describing a termcap entry.

I really want to be able to automate the launch with a shell script, but I have no problem with run a shell script that starts screen with another shell script as the target.

Comment: Related question (no answer): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396752/starting-a-disconnected-screen-session-at-a-specified-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to run an old application inside a fixed screen size using the `screen` command, but you're encountering some confusion about how to achieve this. You're correct that the `-w` option is not for setting the screen size, but rather for setting the width of the terminal's hardstatus line.

Unfortunately, `screen` itself does not provide a built-in way to set a fixed screen size for an application. The terminal size is usually determined by the terminal emulator and the settings of the terminal emulator, not by `screen`.

To work around this, you can try using the `stty` command to set the terminal size before running your application within the `screen` session. Here's an example of how you might create a shell script to automate this process:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Set the terminal size to 80x25
stty rows 25 cols 80

# Start your application inside a screen session
screen -dmS myapp ./runme

# Attach to the screen session to interact with your application
screen -r myapp
```

In this script:

1. We use the `stty` command to set the terminal size to 80x25 before launching the `screen` session.
2. We start the `screen` session in detached mode (`-dmS`) with a name (`myapp`) and specify the command to run (`./runme`).
3. Finally, we attach to the `screen` session to interact with your application using `screen -r myapp`.

This script should help you ensure that your old application runs within the specified terminal size. Remember to adjust the script and terminal size to match your specific requirements.

Please note that some applications may not behave as expected in non-standard terminal sizes, and this approach may not work perfectly for all applications. If your application relies heavily on specific terminal size settings, you may need to look for alternative solutions or consider running it in a more suitable environment, like a virtual machine or container with a compatible terminal size.